# Unique elements in unordered_set, erasing and adding while iterating?

Tags: c++, hashset, unordered-set

I am trying to implement a recursion wherein, I'm passing an `unordered_set<int>` by reference/alias, to reduce space and time complexity. In order to do this, I must iteratively do the following, remove an element, call recursively, and then remove the element from the `unordered_set`.

This is a sample code for the recursive function for printing all permutations of a `vector<int> A` is as follows,

```
void recur(int s, vector<int> &A, vector<int> &curr, vector<vector<int>> &ans, unordered_set<int> &poses){
   if(s == A.size()){
       ans.push_back(curr);
       return;
   }
   for(unordered_set<int>::iterator it = poses.begin() ; it != poses.end() ; it++){
       int temp = *it;
       curr[temp] = A[s];
       poses.erase(it);
       recur(s + 1, A, curr, ans, poses);
       poses.insert(temp);
       curr[temp] = -1;
   }
}
```

You can assume that I'm passing `curr` with all `-1s` initially.

When adding iterating through an `unordered_set` it is guaranteed to find all unique elements. I was wondering whether it would be the same if I remove and add elements back while iterating. Will the position of the element change in the `hashset`, or is it dependent on the implementation.
If this is incorrect could someone also suggest some other way to go about this, since I do not want to pass by value, since it would copy the entire thing for all recursive calls on the stack. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `poses.erase(it);` invalidates `it`. Even if you put the element back in, `it` isn't restored. So the next time you `++` that iterator, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: What if I also do, `it = poses.find(temp)` after insertion? Will I still get unique elements?

Comment: `it = poses.erase(it)` instead of `it++` should do the trick (it would for a `set`, not sure of `unordered_set`)

Comment: But I need to add the element back into the set. Otherwise subsequent recursive calls will suffer. If I add it back after `it=poses.erase(it)`, will I not encounter the element again later?